# Images Error When Rendering Animation

Tags: rendering

when I rendered the animation (in EEVEE), for some reason, some images are like that:
[image: Error]

[image: Image next frame]

[image: Error #2]

[image]

What is the problem here? Why do some frames have this problem??

Comment: Have you tried to render this problematic frames again? Does issue persist?

Comment: there is no problem when rendering each frame. But the animation has around 30-40 frames with that error and it appears randomly. It took too much time to fix, so I re-rendered in PNG format and it is still here.  I can't find the reason for the error

Comment: I looks like graphics card issue ... Eevee is GPU renderer ... Try to render at another machine if you can to check if issue persists. Or check supported graphics cards for blender.

Comment: BTW ... Does it happening during scene rendering or Compositor calculation?

Comment: I rendered it on a different computer and yes, it's still here

I used Compositor calculation in this. I am not sure if it happened on scene rendering or not.

Comment: What Blender version you use? I rendered (old B3.64) 10% size (now I'm at frame 400) and no issue, but ... one thing that seems to be visible - the issued segment is the part of screen with creature (at least in your screenshots) ... also I got crash blender any time creature was enabled for rendering. So I appended creature into a new file to separate issue ... and for some reason any time Noise Texture is plugged into Bump or Displacement node it crash. It can be just my old station, but you can try to unplug Bump and Displacement node to see if issue persists.

Comment: I am using Blender 3.6. 
"Noise Texture is plugged into Bump or Displacement node it crash.". Thanks, I will try to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to #vklidu I finally fixed the problem. The error is on the **Creature Meaty Material**. This material was created in an older Blender and imported into Blender 3.6, it somehow makes the render problematic. Just a simple **BAKE MATERIAL** fixes the problem. Thanks a lot for your help, #vklidu